# Uncle or Aunt without sibling fact

Tags: prolog

I'm wondering how would I be able to call a nephew or niece in a family tree without using a `sibling` fact for prolog. I can't figure out a way to do it by calling the uncle directly.

For example:

```
parent(elli, lisa).
parent(kelly, lisa).

parent(ben, claire).
parent(lisa, claire).

grandparent(X, Y) :- parent(X, Z), parent(Z, Y).
```

Since ellie or kelly is ben's niece, I have the rule that when called by `grandparent(X, claire).` will give elli and kelly as the grandchild of `claire`. How would I make a rule to be able to call `niece(ben, X).` so it'll list all of ben's niece. I can't figure out a way to do it with only the parent fact, the only way of doing it would be to include a sibling fact but is there a way to do it without making a sibling fact?

I'm very new to prolog, literally like a week ago so please excuse me if I don't understand it that well.

Comment: SUrely if my parent's parent is somebody else's parent and that somebody is not my parent then they must be my uncle or aunt.

Comment: Yes, I understand and I could use the same rule of the `grandparent` since it will extract the right info but how would I be able to call `niece(ben, X).` without making another fact? Particularly to see if ben is the uncle of the niece. Right now I can only call `grandparent(X, claire).` to show the grandchild or `grandparent(elli, X).` to show the grandparent. I don't know if I'm thinking about this correctly but what's a way to implement calling ben into the rules?

Comment: After a little messing around I figured it out, I just had to make a `brother` then `uncle` rule and it worked. thanks, your comment put things in perspective. I wasn't sure I could do what I did but it worked so I learned you can do this in prolog.

Comment: @user2318083, add your own answer and accept it. Other people will be able to use your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
brother(X, Y) :- male(X), parent(X, Z), parent(Y, Z), X \= Y.

uncle(X, Y) :- brother(X, Z), parent(Y, Z).
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Should I not put my answer to my question here? Another user above told me to answer my own question.

Comment: Do one or the other: either edit your question to note the answer, or accept your answer.